# 7:3 error syntax error: could not find expected ':' (syntax)

Tags: configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap-{{ template "api.fullname" . }}
data:
{{- range $env-AM := .values.env-AM }}
  {{ $env-AM.key }}: {{ $env-AM.data }}
{{- end }}
```

in values file i declared

```
env-AM:
  - key: key1
    data: data1
  - key: key2
    data: data2
```

can you help please
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
{{- range $key, $val := .values.env-AM }}
{{ $key }}: {{ $val }}
{{- end }}
```

with values:

```
env-AM:
  key1: data1
  key2: data2
```

as suggested in the [docs](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/).